# Is there any word for a situation when a person can't feel satisfaction to let others do his work unless he does it himself?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

I pondered about the words "satisfactory problems" but that is more related to men sexual problems and is diametrically opposed to what I want to know.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! What a good question! For single-word-requests we recommend adding a sentence with a gap for the requested word to make the question clearer. An example might be "When I poke a jelly and it makes a wavy motion, it is ___.", to which the answer might be "wobble".

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to answer this question without much of a context, but I'll try.

Someone who wants to control and do every aspect of something could be called a "control freak".

If it's your boss who doesn't trust you to do things on your own, you could say "my boss is a control freak, an obsessive micromanager".

Caveat: "control freak" can also be interpreted as someone who is obsessed with controlling others, for instance spouses who intrusively spy on their partners.

An interesting related word which is used in business is "overmanagement":

> **overmanagement**: 
>   (*business*) excessive management; micromanagement

So if the situation is anything like that, you could try something along the lines of "overmanagement issues".

Comment: Thanks for the struggle neptun but the situation with me is a bit different, let me break it down for you. For instance if I goto a barber's shop and tell him to get my beard done, no matter how good he does it, in the end of it or at home, I still wouldn't be satisfied with the way he makes it but on the other hand If I do it my self, I would be feeling good.

Answer (score 0):

The person is **unable to delegate**.

To *delegate* is to commit or assign a task to someone else (often a subordinate) or to entrust one's work to another.

If we plug this phrase into a search engine, the [top](http://www.turningmanagersintoleaders.com/unable-delegate-effectively-may-reason/) [few pages](https://www.nursingtimes.net/roles/nurse-managers/how-to-delegate-your-way-to-a-better-working-life/200642.article) discusses the type of character you describe:

*"Why should team members dedicate their time and effort to a project when you, the manager, might jump in and take over?"*

*"It is important to achieve the right balance, because delegating too much may result in a loss of control, while failing to delegate or not delegating enough can lead to duties not being completed"*

Comment: Thanks for the struggle Chemomechanics but the situation with me is a bit different, let me break it down for you. For instance if I goto a barber's shop and tell him to get my beard done, no matter how good he does it, in the end of it or at home, I still wouldn't be satisfied with the way he makes it but on the other hand If I do it my self, I would be feeling good.